# Getting HTTP/1.1 404 error on ReadyAPI REST virtual service on specific resource paths

Tags: rest, post, groovy, get, ready-api

Why is readyAPI responding with a 404 error when the recourse path is set other than `/test` in a REST Virtual service.

**/test**

[image]

[image]

```
Sun May 29 16:42:53 BST 2022: DEBUG: http-outgoing >> 
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:9019
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/16.0.1)


Sun May 29 16:42:53 BST 2022: DEBUG: http-incoming << 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 May 2022 15:42:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1249
Server: Jetty(9.4.40.v20210413)

[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xff][0xcd]W[0xdb]r[0xe2]F[0x10][0xfd][0x15][0xad][0x9e][0xb9]H[0x2]q+[0xca][0x15][0x8c]|[0x8b][0x8d][0xa1][0x0]o[0x92]J[0xb9][0xa8]A[0x1a]`6[0x92]F;3[0xda]][0xd6][0xcb][0xd7][0xe4]G[0xd3][0xad][0x1b][0x17][0xcb]v[0xaa][0xe2][0xad]
O[0xe2]tk[0xa6][0xa7][0xfb][0x9c]#[0xa9]?[0xe7]gZ[0xe0]y[0x82]Jy[0xe6][0x91]/[0xcc][0xab][0x11][0x97]KE~Y[0x7][0x84][0xf9]5[0x97][0x7][0xfd]z[0x1e][0xd7][0xfa][0xb3]x)][0xc1][0x96]T[0xdc][0xd2][0xed][0x19][0x17][0x1e][0x15][0xb][0x97][0x87]+&[0x2][0xa2][0x18][0xf][0x17]4[0xec][0xd7][0x8f][0x93][0xb4][0xfe][0x90][0x87][0x8a][0xb8]j[0xa0][0x14][0x80][0xb1][0xa2][0xc7][0xb][0x1d][0xc1][0x14]7u[0x88]"gO[0xfa][0x9c][0xeb][0xbd]'=[0xdb][[0xef][0xe9][0xe5][0xd5][0xe9][0x15][0xfd]h?H,-[0xeb][0x87][0xd9]h7[0x8c]v[0xab]i[0xfe]xq[0xa1]g[0x85]b[0x1]e[0x95]"^[0x94]
;f[0xff][0xe6][0xdb][0x88][0xbe][0xb4]?,[0xef][0x93]p[0x1d][0x93]5[0xa6]$[0xff][0x3][0xea][0x11][0xdf]g[0xa4]X[0x17][0x2][0x0]K[0xe2]S[0xb9][0xe2][0xc2][0xa5][0xf][0x92][0x8a][0x1b][0xf][0xd0][0x90]$~L1[0x18][0x91]k[0xa8][0x1b]0iXK[0xaa]HMR%[0x98][0xb7][0xa6]2;[0x85][0xa0].[0x8b][0x18][0x15]V[0x19][0xc3][0x12]YYS[0x88]ETH[0x1e][0xce][0x99][0xf2][0x11][0x19]1hlE[0x87]2[0xa5][0xba]'[0x1]B[0xe][0xf6]&[0xa9][0xb5][0x80][0x6]I[0xa3][0x0]K[0xce][0xf8][0xda] [0x2][0xbe]d>[0xbd][0x8f][0x3]h[0x16][0xe4]5[0xec]n[0xd5]0[0x1b][0xd5]N[0xab]e[0xeb][0xbb]J[0xda][0x17],*[0xb9][0xc0][0x83][0x15]3[0xa9][0xe8][0x8a]+[0xe2]O[0x4][0xf7]bWM[0x4]sag[0xab]]3[0xf0]W[0x12][0xbc][0xf8][0xe6][0xfa]Wl[0xa5][0xce][0xf9][0xb7]gy3[0xec][0xdf][0x9c]@[0xc0][0xa8][0xed][0xc1][0x8b]"[0x16][0xae][0x87][0x1b]"p[0x2][0xa6]qt[0xcf][0xc0][0xfb][0x14]K[0x15]$M+"kABo[0x8e]a[0xbd][0xd7]8[0xd9]C[0x91][0xd5][0xca]a[0xd2][0xe5]qrK[0x6];[0x14]+[0xa4][0xde][0xc7][0xc1]<[0x1]e[0xca][0x9d][0x8]90[0x88]"[0x9f]Q8[0xf4][0x8a][0xf8][0x92]Vt7[0x16][0x82][0x86].[0x12][0xf6][0xea]|[0xa2][0xef][0x81][0xd9]6Xr[0xec][0xf3][0xdf]80[0x9f][0xb8][0xd4][0x3][0x9a][0xe1]$,[0xa3]j4[0xab][0x96]aY[0x9a]a[0xf7][0xec].T[0x5])[0xd0]s[0x1f]NV[0x8][0xe5]IW[0xd9]|[0x1d]q2[0xdd][0xb1][0xcf][0xbe]0r<[0xde][0x19][0x9][0xdd][0xfd][0xe] IW[0xb8]c!5!`[0x9a]mm[0xc4]<[0xcf][0xa7]_[0x99][0xbb][0xd1][0xa6]H[0xb][0x97][0xa9]mz[0x8f][0xb7]$[0xee][0x6][0xb][0x4][0x16][0xb8][0xdc][0xc3][0x95][0x86][0xbf][0x99][0xa6]f^^c[0x1e][0xf6]E[0xa4]g[0xc3][0xd1][0xcb][0xac][0xfd][0xff][0xeb]"=
;S[0xb1][0xbd][0x12]<[0x8e][0xa0][0xc6]?_`*[0xa3][0xc3]d-[0xb8][0xfe][0xac][0xb6][0xe3][0x15][0xd6][0x2][0xe9][0xd6][0xc9]
Y[0xe9]{}^[0xc6][0xfe]
fE[0xb1][0xc6][0xbc]![0xe3][0x84][0x1b][0xd8][0xf]DFi[0x8d][0xf][0xb7][0xf7]#[0xe7][0x8f][0xc1][0xe5][0xfc] 1[0xd3][0xc4][0x9e][0xb7]y[0xbe]C[0xb][0x8a][0xc1][0xad][0xf7]<`![0xb0][0xc5][0xd3][0x6]+EE[0xc8]9:M^[0x17]H[0x8][0xa4][0x9b][0x88][0xd3][0x99]8[0xda]5[0xf][0xa8][0xe6]d[0xb1][0xa3][0x1b][0x14][0xb][0xa8][0xf4][0xb9][0x2][0x9e][0xb]4[0x1b][0xd3][0xea][0x19][0xc6][0x1]~[0x11][0xa2]-[0x99][0x9d][0x14]E[0x93][0x99]Q[0x9f]"[0xf5]s[0xaa][0xb6]r[0xaa][0xa2]q[0x10][0x1][0xd4][0x97]*[0xdf][0xaa],[0xc7][0x7][0xec][0xb5][0x8c][0xdc]?[0xb2]f[0x17][0xb3]Q4[0xc0][0xf9][0xb4][[0x96]e5[0x9b][0x15][0x9d]![0x10][0xae][0xf8][0xde]gJ3p[0xa4]F[0xd7]nt[0xd2][0xff][0x13]8[0xe6][0xde][0xb7][0xc][0xbb][0xd5]l[0xb5]P[,[0x0][0xbf]~[0x98][0xde][0x1][0xba]Q*[0x92][0xbd]z=[0x81][0xe4][0x89][0xed][0xd6][0x99]L[0x3][0xf5]=^[0x9f]&[0x93]2L{1[0xbd]p[0x16]#X[0xee]sLB[0x95][0xb0][0xd3][0xac][0xc1][0x8][0xa3][0xcc][0xe7][0xac][0xc2][r[0xd7]:t[0xbd][0xd3][0x9c][0x17][0xfd]J[0xc6][0x89][0xc5][0x88]![0xf7]y,2[0xfa][0xc1][0xd6]([0x0][0x2][0xd6][0xa2]2[0x7][0xc5][0xd6]D[0xe9]e[0xd6][0x7][0xc3][0xe8]Vr[0xe8][0xa8][0x15][0xc5][0x11][0xf4]"[0x9e]+2$[0x91][0xdc]p[0xa5][0xb9][0x82]KY]ro[0xab]-[0xc9][0xfa][0xfd]{[0xb6]D[0x17][0xce]6[0x1d][0xa6]C[0xed][0xd7][0xc1]p|>[0x83][0xc8]W[0x1e][0xc2]|[0xa7][0x9c][0x7][0x97]>[0xec][0x9c][0x1a]+[0xf0][0x84][0xc9][0xd9][0x81][0xef][0x16][0x86][0xcb][0xe4][0xe4]{[0x98][0xfa][0xff][0xec][0xf6][0xe1][0x0][0xce][0x1e]$[0xa5] [0x1a][0xb6][0x12]1[0xcd]h[0x92]<>[0x89][0xcf]$[0xc9]d[0xbb]K[0x3][0x98]=![0xee]_dR[0xc5][0xfe][0xae]Wj %w[0xc7]9[0x5]S[0xce]>[0x83][0xf7][0xcc][0xb4]w[0x8f]h[0x94][0x94][0xa7]/1[0x1][0x11]n[0xf5][0x13]<d[0x97][0xd0]\[0xb2][0xae][0x9a]UA[0xbd][0xc5][0xe1]<[0xe4][0xc9]s[0xee][0xdf]=P[0xe0][0x99][0xad]b|[0x9d][0x1a][0xea][0xbb]][0xa5]T#[0xf6][0x9b]*[0xb2][0xf]T[0xd4]4m[0xc3],QQ[0xdb][0xee]t;[0xcd][0xb6][0xf5]_[0x19][0xd1]5;U[0x13][0xce]\[0x9d][0xdd]]^[0xdd]\[0xce][0xcf][0xc7][0xbf][0xdf][0xdc]_[0xbd]"'[0xfb]m5[0xd9]o[0x8b][0xe9]U[0xc5]4[0xa1] [0xb3]\1[0xe5][0xe5]>[0x97]Oq@[0xb9][0xa3][0xe1][0x8b][0xcc][0xcf]k[0xd4][0xcf]PJ[0xa6][0x8a]C[0xa1][0xe4]y[0xef][0xa1][0x94]|[0xb6][0xfb]|[0xdc][0x1][0x9a][0xfe][0x8a][0x84][0x9a][0xbb][0xc7]$>[0x82][0x17][0x84][0xf4]=[0xfb][0x9a]D[0x11][0xf8][0x12][0x13]j[0xe3][0x91][0xed][0x87][0xf][0xfa][0xa1][0xc4][0xaa][0x8b][0x17][0x87][0xf5][0xe][0xda]z[0xc4]b[0x12]~[0xcd][0x9f][0xf3][0xf0]&[0x88][0xb8]PN[0xc][0xef][0x12][0x90]o[0xec]vp[0xc3]n[0xd7][0xaf][0xef][0xbf][0xb4][0xc3][0xef][0xa8][0xa3]o[0xa4]z[0xd9][0xf7]T[0x1d]>[0xe4][0xfe][0x1][0xe1][0x96]s{[0xcd][0x0][0x0]
```

**/sendEmail**

[image]

[image]

```
Sun May 29 16:47:12 BST 2022: DEBUG: http-outgoing >> 
POST /sendEmail HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:9019
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/16.0.1)


Sun May 29 16:47:12 BST 2022: DEBUG: http-incoming << 
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 29 May 2022 15:47:12 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.4.40.v20210413)

0
```

Are there any specific rules to set the resource paths?
I intend to set the resource path as /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/ for the first action(SendEmail) but it's failing.

second action SendToken is behaving the same, if the path is set as /test it response with a 200 ok status but returns a 404 error on setting the path to /v2/token.

Groovy scripts are used for creating the response.

any explanation for this behavior in ReadyAPI?

Comment: i don't see in your question any line of groovy - better to remove this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the resource path, it was missing.

I assumed it was automatically added. after updating it started working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be setting up your operations correctly. It seems like you're reusing the same endpoint but giving them different names and that is likely the reason why you're getting behavior like this.

What I'd recommend is taking a look at [ReadyAPI's documentation on how to add in new operations](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/virtualization/configure/create-operations.html). I think that once you set up the operations correctly you should be able to access them properly.

https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/virtualization/configure/create-operations.html